# How do I make an automatic server backup in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, server-administration, minecraft-java-edition-server

There is no built-in implementation in a Vanilla Minecraft server to force a save every X minutes, then back up the files into a folder. I know how to do log rotations and I can also do a normal backup using Window's `XCOPY` or `ROBOCOPY`, but have no idea how to do it when the server is running to prevent possible data corruption.

How can I perform an automatic backup that ensures a consistent state of the game data?

The server is running on Windows.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it seems to be asking for a software recommendation, which is off-topic.

Comment: @ktash Is there a way for me to reword it in a way so that it is on topic?

Comment: This question is being discussed at [meta]: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6962/why-was-a-question-about-minecraft-server-backup-closed-considering-there-is-a

Comment: I'm just confused as to why it was not closed when I first asked it.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ yeah I feel your pain .. some moderators just quickly vote to close without even asking for more information regarding your question ...  Oh and also a bombardment of downvotes .. haha ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for a list of Server managers, which should help you with more than just backups.
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Programs_and_editors/Server_wrappers

Answer (score 9):

On Linux, I came up with a rather basic solution which you can find here:  https://github.com/pwaller/waitsilence

The idea is to use `inotifywait | waitsilence` to determine when minecraft has finished writing its backup out. That allows you to avoid corruption.

If you run your minecraft session inside a named screen (e.g, `screen -S minecraft`), then you can send text into minecraft's input with `screen -r -S minecraft -X stuff $'\nsave-all\nsave-off\n'`. The `-r` flag prevents the screen writing save-all, save-off into the screen if it is currently attached.

`inotifywait` then writes what file modifications are seen, and I wrote `waitsilence` (above) to wait until nothing has been written for a few seconds.

This can all be put into a `backup.sh` script which is then run via cron.

Comment: Do you have a version of this for Windows?

Comment: I'm afraid not :(

Comment: Darn. I need this for Windows though.

Comment: Hi! I appreciate I'm (very) late to this party, but just wanted to say thanks for this. It's really helpful. 
One question: I notice you include "stuff" before the minecraft commands. Is this just some form of padding (it's not a terminal command on my machine). I find it very odd that the commands don't seem to work without "stuff" even though it isn't technically valid. Thanks.

Comment: You're going to pinch yourself, as I just pinched myself reading your comment. `stuff` is the command. As in "to stuff some things into the terminal".

Comment: Seems like this solution has a massive race condition: Minecraft could write more data right after you start copying the world. That said, I'm glad someone attempted to answer the question as asked :)

Comment: @Navin, as to my understanding this is expected with "save-all". That is, the backup is most likely not completely consistent. "save-all flush" solves this by locking the server during the process.

More interested though: does this _break_ anything or make the backups faulty for restore?